# Data in Azure Redis Cache

Tags: azure-redis-cache

Is there an easy way to see what's in my Redis Cache on Azure? I mean some type of tool?

I know how to do it programmatically but sometimes while writing code, I want to be able to quickly see what's in my Redis cache without having to switch to some other code.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Besides programming, generally, there are two ways to explore the data on Azure Redis Cache, which include Azure Redis Console on Azure portal or Redis clients like the standard client `redis-cli`.

1. Using Azure Redis Console on Azure portal, please see the offical tutorial [Redis console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/redis-cache/cache-configure#redis-console).
2. Using redis clients. If you are using Windows, you can download [Redis on Windows](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/releases/) which be released by MSFT. After install it, you can find the redis tool called `redis-cli.exe` and use it to connect Azure Redis Cache as below.

   If not enabled ssl, type in `CMD` as below.

   ```
   C:> redis-cli.exe -h <your redis cache name>.redis.cache.windows.net -p 6379 -a <access key>
   ```

   Or you can use the third party GUI client, such as [Redis Desktop Manager (cross-platform)](https://github.com/uglide/RedisDesktopManager/releases), [Redis Studio (only for Windows)](https://github.com/cinience/RedisStudio/releases).

Fig 1. Using Redis Desktop Manager to connect Azure Redis Cache within SSL
[image]

Hope it helps. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.